# About the try and catch in 2d arrays (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays, try-catch

I'm working on chess board where pieces move randomly over a 7 by 7 array. Everything is 0 by default, and when I move to a new position it is shown by a counter on the array.

My problem is that my movements keep exiting the bounds of the array. How do I disallow that using the try and catch statement?

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Chess {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[][] board = new int[8][8];
        int[] vertical = {-1, -2, -2, -1, 1, 2, 2, 1};
        int[] horizontal = {2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1, 1, 2};

        int counter = 1;
        int currentrow;
        int currentcolumn;
        int check = 0;
        Random rand = new Random();
        int rnum = rand.nextInt((7 - 0) + 1) + 0;

        currentrow = rnum;
        currentcolumn = rnum;

        //set the knight in a random position on the board first

        board[currentrow][currentcolumn] = counter;

        //move it on the board

        try {
            while(check == 0) {
                int rnum1 = rand.nextInt((7 - 0) + 1) + 0;
                currentrow += vertical[rnum1] ;
                currentcolumn += horizontal[rnum1] ;

                if(board[currentrow][currentcolumn]==0) {
                    ++counter;
                    board[currentrow][currentcolumn]=counter;
                } 
                else {
                    currentrow -= vertical[rnum1] ;
                    currentcolumn -= horizontal[rnum1] ;
                }
            }
        } 
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}

        System.out.printf("it stopped at %d\n",counter);

        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%3d", board[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.printf("%d\n", currentrow);
        System.out.printf("%d\n", currentcolumn);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can replace rand.nextInt((7 - 0) + 1) + 0; with rand.nextInt(8);

Comment: Your code is far from readable: Too much empty lines, inconsistent indentation, and others. I will format it for you. Please take care of that next time. Additionally, please exactly desribe the error (I assume an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) with a stacktrace and the line where it occurs. For getting the stacktrace, please do not just swallow the exception but print it: `catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) { e.printStacktrace(); }`

Comment: That's not what `try - catch` is for.

Comment: Do you want a `finally` block ? or just move everything after the `try...catch` in the `catch` block?

Comment: To clarify Maroun's comment: an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown to signal a bug in your code. Catching the exception won't fix the bug: it will hide it. Such an exception should not be thrown in the first place. Fix your code to avoid it, by making sure you don't access indices that don't exist. BTW, your description says that the board is 7x7. But your code creates an array of 8x8.